# check which one of 2-4 possible servers has a the file; then copy it using powershell

Tags: powershell

Powershell rookie and need to copy a file; it may be on server A  OR B (never both)
Whichever server this resides on; I need to copy it to  serverX

So far this is what i have but can't figure out, can anyone point me in right direction?

```
$source =  "\\serverA\path\file.txt"
$source2 =  "\\serverB\path\file.txt"
$destination = "\\serverX\path\file.txt"

IF (!(Test-Path $source)
{Copy-Item -Path $source -Destination $destination 
}
ELSE 
(!(Test-Path $source2)
{Copy-Item -Path $source2 -Destination $destination 
}
```

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Does this code not work for you? If not, how is it breaking? In what way are you stuck?

Comment: at some point; there may be a File on either Server A or B or C or D; that i would eed to find and copy to ServerX but figure out the 2 then can figure the 4 possible sources

Comment: `@(@($source, $source2, <etcetera>) | where { test-path $_ })` gives you a collection of accessible paths. You can pass this directly to `copy-item` or else add an explicit `[0]` at the end to get only the first one.

Comment: Hey Alroc,  I know my test file is on serverB, the code or one of my variations of my code; stops looking aafter failing at ServerA and does not look at ServerB

Comment: @user3191894 The code that you've posted. Is that the version that "stops looking after failing at ServerA"? We can't help you debug if you're looking at one version of the code and posting a different version. Post the code your're running and **exactly** what happens, including any error messages. The `-verbose` flag may be helpful to you.

Comment: @JeroenMostert if you don't flesh that out into a a full script and post it as an answer, I will :). That's a good use of `test-path` I haven't considered before.

Comment: Yep that is code it stops at "..Copy-Item : Cannot find path..."

Comment: It's because you are trying to copy it if it *isn't* there!  Remove the ! from the if and else statements.

Comment: Yep that worked Thanks! .$source =  "\\serverA\path\file.txt"
$source2 =  "\\serverB\path\file.txt"
$destination = "\\serverX\path\file.txt"  
IF (Test-Path $source)
{Copy-Item -Path $source -Destination $destination 
}
ELSE
{
IF (Test-Path $source2)
{Copy-Item -Path $source2 -Destination $destination 
}
}

Comment: PS:  I also was missing the second IF in original code posted, thanks all for replies!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using the "not" operator with your test-path statement, the evaluation of the condition is true if the file does *NOT* exist.  Accordingly, the copy-item command is failing because there is no file to copy.

Remove the "not" operator from the if and else evaluations so that the following code block runs if the file is present:

```
IF (Test-Path $source){}
ELSE (Test-Path $source2){}
```

Comment: Thanks hat is what I tried first, thanks all for other resoinses too, will continue to improve the pocess and learn

Answer (score 1):

```
#Don't use the Not operator
IF (Test-Path $source) instead of
IF (!(Test-Path $source)
#otherwise it returns false and you don't come to the part where the file
#would get copied
```

I would do it like this:

```
$paths = @("\\serverA\path\file.txt","\\serverB\path\file.txt")
$destination = "\\serverX\path\file.txt"

foreach ($path in $paths){
    if (Test-Path $path){
        Copy-Item -Path $path -Destination $destination
        break
    }
}
```

Throw all your paths into an array and then iterate through the paths with foreach. break should escape out of this loop if your file was already found and copied.